# Padding used in background drawable affects the ImageView's main drawable

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I have a layer-list drawable the achieves an effect similar to the image below by applying padding, and stroke to every layer.

[image]

The code of the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#99ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp" />
            <corners
                android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#88ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp" />
            <corners
                android:radius="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#77ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#66ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#55ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#44ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#33ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#22ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#11ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0.5dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="0.5dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#00ff0000"
                android:width="0.5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But the padding used to create the effect also affects the ImageView's main drawable, making the image smaller than it should be. I tried using a LayerDrawable instead, but the padding still affected all the layers, which were above the drawable.

Setting android:cropToPadding to true/false did nothing. I have android:scaleType set to centerCrop.

How can I prevent the background drawable's padding from affecting the main image drawable?

Here is a visual example:
If I write this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle_green"/>
```

I get result below. I want to disable the padding that was applied to the green rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Remove the padding in the last layer?

Comment: Well, the padding that was applied to the main drawable is bigger than 0.5dp, but it's true that the padding in the last layer was unneeded.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the padding at effect, and also the XML/code initializing the `ImageView`?

Comment: I found [setPaddingMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setPaddingMode(int)) but it was only added in Lollipop, and it somehow really messed up the imageview (the borders were huge)

Comment: I added an example to the question. The ImageView is initialized in layout XMLs, but I set the drawables dynamically.

Comment: So you want to have the layered background replaced by the new drawable?

Comment: I don't know any better way to create this kind of gradient border, if there is a better way to create it without padding, I'd gladly replace it. But for now I'm looking for a solution that prevents padding to be applied to the main drawable.

Comment: I don't see any extra padding applied to the main drawable in your picture, except for the border area itself. If you want the border to be _replaced_, then simply apply it to the `src` attribute of the `ImageView` instead of the `background`.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I didn't say anything about _extra_ padding. I don't the border to be replaced. Let's say I put a triangle as the src drawable. I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/rNibOll.png), but I want [this](http://i.imgur.com/NoIj8SH.png)

Comment: OK, perhaps you can remove the padding by using insets instead of padding. Or you can use a custom PNG without padding as a layer. Or you can create two overlapping image views.

Comment: ah well, I don't know how to define insets in xml drawables. I avoided using multiple overlapping ImageViews because it's inefficient (i think) in a listview. But I guess there is no other choice. Thank you.

Comment: You can define the inset values in the layer by moving your padding attributes to inside the `<item>` tag. It might work - you can try it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

try this for ur `imageview`.

i think ur doing like this..

```
android:background="@drawable/padding" // ur drawable xml code
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  // ur image
```

do like this

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" // ur image
android:src="@drawable/padding"  // ur drawable xml code
```

**edit:**

try this too

```
setImageResource(R.drawable.padding);  // ur drawable xml code
```

and

```
setBackgroundDrawable  // ur image
```

Comment: Well, i'm actually setting the drawables dynamically using setImageDrawable and setBackgroundDrawable, because I use a listview, but that doens't make a difference here. If I switch up the two images the drawable would cover up the edges of the image, I don't want that.

Comment: read my comment again. I don't want to switch up the two drawables, because the drawable with the padding would cover some parts of the main drawable.

Comment: if there is no other solution, I will use this solution

Comment: i think without padding cant achieve this...  try with nested rectangles..hope works...